# Are glass baby food jars safe to reuse?

Tags: infant, safety, food

I've been feeding my daughter store-bought baby food in glass jars, but I plan on starting to make her food myself.  Is it safe to wash and re-use the jars I already have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://wholesomebabyfood.momtastic.com/FreezePage.htm

> Glass that is not specifically manufactured for freezing has the
>   unfortunate ability to crack, leave behind tiny, microscopic shards
>   and fragments and also is prone to bursting. Baby food jars are not
>   manufactured for freezing or for extreme heating. BALL, makers of home
>   canning products, manufactures 4 ounce jars specifically for freezing
>   as do other manufactures.

So, for as long as you aren't planning to freeze (cold temperature) or start canning food (hot temperature) for long-term storage, you should be fine.

We used the baby food jars in the beginning, and now we use them for various things like carrying drinks (water/milk/juice) for our little one, or carrying snacks/food in it when we are out and about. It works pretty well for us.

Comment: My family did this, too. :D

Comment: Also hot-water or steam sterilising is probably not a good idea.

Comment: *Glass that is not specifically manufactured for freezing has the unfortunate ability to crack, leave behind tiny, microscopic shards and fragments* — It'd be pretty easy to spot a cracked glass, no?